# Coefficient in Sparse Signal Recovery

Tags: compressive-sensing, sparsity

To understand the idea of sparse signal recovery described in [Sparsity and Incoherence in Compressive Sampling](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611957), I decided to build a toy problem. Suppose the sparse signal that we want to reconstruct $x^0$ is $n=1000$ dimensional and only $S=9$ of its entries are nonzero. For simplicity, I pick the transform matrix $U$ to be a DFT matrix and I randomly sample $m$ values from $Ux^0$ (transform coefficients) to use them as our measurements $y$. In other words,
$$y = U_{\Omega} x^0.$$

Based on the theorem given in the paper, signal recovery is possible with constrained $\ell_1$ norm minimization if the number of measurements $m$ satisfies the following condition:
$$m \geq C \mu^2(U) S \log n$$ for a positive constant $C$. In my toy problem, I know that $\mu(U)=1$, $S=9$ and $n=1000$, but I do not know the constant $C$! I looked at the paper over and over again and I think I am missing something. Could you please explain to me how to determine the value of $C$?